How do I enable compilation of code that would otherwise be compiled out when running Rust doctests?
Suppose I have a crate that contains a module that's compiled only when a certain feature is enabled (and I do not want to enable that feature by default). However, I also want its documentation to be visible when doing a plain cargo doc, so I also compile it when documenting:
#[cfg(any(feature="enable_foo", doc))]
mod foo;

In the source file that implements the module, the documentation has a number of doctests. A minimal reproducible example would look something like this:
/// Does nothing.
///
/// ```
/// # use crate::foo::do_nothing;
/// do_nothing();
/// ```
fn do_nothing() {}

(Try it on the Rust playground – you will need to change the "Select what to build" selector in the top left to "Test" to reproduce.)
However, this causes cargo test to fail when not explicitly enabling the enable_foo feature. The problem is that because the module foo is documented, the doctest code finds the test cases in its documentation; and then because the feature enable_foo is disabled, the doctests can't run the code that was compiled out.
One possible fix to this problem is to enable the doctests for the module only if the feature is enabled. There are a couple of questions already (1, 2) about how to conditionally enable doctests based on a feature, although in this particular situation, it is much easier to just compile out the entire module when scanning for doctests unless the feature is enabled:
#[cfg(any(feature="enable_foo", all(doc, not(doctest))))]
mod foo;

Although that works, and would serve as a suboptimal fix for my problem if nothing better is available, I'm interested in doing the opposite: compiling in the code when running doctests, even if the feature is disabled. The obvious way to do it is like this:
#[cfg(any(feature="enable_foo", doc, doctest))]
mod foo;

but this does not work, producing the exact same output as it does without the , doctest in the conditional compilation block. My conclusions from this are that the doctest configuration flag is set while looking for doctests, but not while running them. (Adding test rather than doctest likewise has no effect on the behaviour.)
So my question is: is there a way to conditionally compile in code while running doctests (as opposed to when scanning for them), if it would otherwise be compiled out? This could either be done at the source code level (using some conditional compilation attribute that I'm currently unaware of to include it), or at the Cargo level (asking Cargo to force on certain features for any doc-testing run).
I did find a Cargo-based solution that works on my local machine, but suspect that it's incorrect and would not work when the crate is published: adding the crate as a dev-dependency of itself, with the feature enabled. I suspect this is wrong because the tests are looking at the code from the dev-dependency rather than the crate itself, so once the crate is published, the tests will run against the published version of the crate rather than the local version that is being worked on.
(There have been a few questions already (1, 2) about how to enable features only for testing purposes, but they apply to the interaction of multiple crates, whereas this question is about testing just a single crate, so the answers there aren't applicable here.)

"once the crate is published, the tests will run against the published version of the crate rather than the local version that is being worked on" – why would that be different now? If it works without a published version of the crate IMO it should work when one is published as well. Either it's using the local version now and then, or it's trying to use the published version in both cases but that would mean it should fail to compile now.

@cafce25: because the self-dependency is specified using path="." which probably wouldn't be allowed in a published crate.

Note that your playground fails to compile the doctests even without the feature because you forgot to make foo and do_nothing public. A better reproduction would be: playground

Sounds like a lot of fuss over just running cargo doc --all-features (or equivalent) if that's the end result you're after.

path="." seems to be supported since "Note: crates.io does not allow packages to be published with dependencies on code published outside of crates.io itself (dev-dependencies are ignored) […]" – Specifying Dependencies - The Cargo Book

(And the "or equivalent" in @kmdreko's comment above for docs.rs is described here).
